# New SSL cert on Exchange server, now fails connectivity analyzer

Tags: ssl-certificate, exchange-2003

Exchange Server 2003 SP2.  Had a problem installing SSL cert so I installed a hotfix that fixed the inability to utilize SHA2 certs.  Hotfix and cert are now loaded.  Went into IIS manager, set outlook web access properties, directory security tab: switched to the new cert, turned off anonymous access, checked the two boxes referencing integrated windows auth and basic auth.  In the secure communications tab I checked the box to use SSL but left use 128bit unchecked.

When I run connectivity manager, I get the error: 
"The Microsoft Connectivity Analyzer wasn't able to obtain the remote SSL certificate."
"The certificate couldn't be validated because SSL negotiation wasn't successful. This could have occurred as a result of a network error or because of a problem with the certificate installation"

Attempt to goto the webmail address on http gives an error that it must be viewed on the secure channel.  attempt to view webmail at the https://mail.domain.com fails with "ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED".

Suggestions very welcome.  Thank you.

Comment: One difference I see is it is missing the statement that there is a matching private key.  I am checking to see if that is required or the problem here.
reference: http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2007/08/21/how-to-install-a-public-3rd-party-ssl-certificate-on-iis-on-sbs-2003.aspx

Comment: It was the problem.  The lack of the statement of a matching private key led me to info about how to generate a private key.
link http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/security-issues/troubleshooting-ssl-related-issues-server-certificate
led me towards a command of "certutil -repairstore".

While I am still unable to activesync properly, I can do webmail - which is proof that the function is working mostly.  I would mark my answer as answer, but i dont see means to.